# Version for "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" to support MSAL?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-ad-msal, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-authentication

What is version for "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" to support MSAL?
I can see it is still internally using "Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no version of `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` that supports MSAL.  This Service Bus library is a legacy package that has been deprecated is and only receiving critical security and bug fixes.

The [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus) package is the recommended replacement.  As part of the current generation of the Azure SDK, it integrates with the [Azure.Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet) library for authentication/authorization.  `Azure.Identity` uses MSAL internally and will continue to evolve and adhere to recommended guidance for identity management and security.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jesse. It helped.
Can you help me understand which corresponding msal library for :
1. Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging
2. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Comment: Those are both deprecated legacy packages that pre-date MSAL.  Neither supports it nor, to my knowledge, are there any plans to upgrade the AppAuthentication package to do so.